64 bit kernel development
I'm writing just for fun and for personal study a small 64-bit kernel entirely in assembler (nasm). In a blog I found this macro that would be useful for me to define the IDT with all the functions that hook interrupts etc. the macro is this:
%define CODE_SEG    0x0008
BASE_OF_SECTION     equ 0x8000

%macro .idtentry 3
dw ((BASE_OF_SECTION + %1 - $$) & 0xFFFF) - 1024 ; Low word bits (0-15) of offset
dw %2 ; Code-Segment-Selector
db 0 ; Always zero
db %3 ; Type and Attributes
dw ((BASE_OF_SECTION + %1 - $$) >> 16) & 0xFFFF ; Middle bits (16-31) of offset dd ((BASE_OF_SECTION + %1 - $$) >> 32) & 0xFFFFFFFF ; High bits (32-64) of offset dd 0 ; Reserved

here is an example of expansion of the above macro:
.idtentry ISR_Division_by_Zero, CODE_SEG, 0x8F  ;0 (Divide by zero)

when I compile the kernel (elf_64) it gives me the following error when I try to expand the macro to define the various functions (division by zero etc). Why?
Thanks
When I try to compile and expand this macro into a sample assembly in binary format
it gives me no error.

What is the error it gives you? I am guessing it might be operator may only be applied to scalar values?

Related / possible duplicates: How to do computations with addresses at compile/linking time? / Solution needed for building a static IDT and GDT at assemble/compile/link time

Yes the error is: operator may only be applied to scalar values (on & operator)

When geenrating a bin file the start address (org) is known and all the symbols can be found within the single binary file that is generated. It appears the tutorial you took this macro from builds the bootloader/stage1/stage2&kernel as one binary file starting at 0x7c00 with the kernel at 0x8000. Although that tutorial has many ASM files they are included (not linked). As a result all the labels can be resolved and the assembler (at assemble time) can shift bits <</>> and perform &/| etc as the symbols for the exceptions/IRQs are fixed constants.

When you use -f elf64 to generate object files the assembler doesn't know what the origin point is, the address where the current segment begins etc so it has to emit addresses that need to be fixed up at link time. Unfortunately the linker LD/ELF doesn't support << />> / & and | on addresses that the assembler marks as relocatable. NASM knows this so reports any attempt to perform unsupported bit manipulation as an error. To get around this you can either use the linker (and a linker script) to build the IDT or you have to fill in the IDT function offsets at run time (in code)

The two links the Peter posted in his comment provide some ideas and code to do just that.
